# Redux : store.getState return undefined value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Why my store.getState return undefined value!  I'm quite new with ReactJS & Redux here my code

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const initialState = {
salary: 1000,
}

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD":
        state = {
            salary: state.salary+=action.payload,
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

store.subscribe(() => {
console.log('Update salary: ', store.getState.salary);
})

store.dispatch({
type: "ADD",
payload: 2000,
});
```

Console : Update salary:  – undefined

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`getState` is a method, call it

```
console.log('Update salary: ', store.getState().salary);
```

And you should fix even your reducer

```
case "ADD":
   return {salary: state.salary + action.payload}
```

It has to return the new state, you don't return anything

Comment: Ursus, thanks for your help but when I called as method I get
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.getState().salary')

Comment: Ursus, modified return case like you said it's work now
switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD":
            return state = {

                salary: state.salary+= action.payload
            }
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }

Comment: perfect. but don't assign to state again. Just return the new state :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the state directly as done in `case "ADD"`.
Instead return a new state.
Use code

```
case "ADD":
    return {
        salary: state.salary+=action.payload
    }
```

also use `store.getState().salary` to retrieve the data.

This will work.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

By returning the state value solved the problem!

```
switch (action.type) { 
case "ADD": 

return { salary: state.salary+= action.payload } 
break; 

default: break; }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.